# Spinner Android Showing different display in Different sdks

Tags: android, styles, android-spinner, android-4.4-kitkat, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a simple spinner code,In my PC **Android API** is updated to **lollipop** and my colleague PC its **kitkat**,But the UI is Display like below,Why this happen

***Lollipop***

[image: lollipop]

***Kitkat***

[image: Kitkat]

**activity.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#cfcfcf"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:entries="@array/arr"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Style.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
            -->
     <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/mySpinnerItemStyle</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/mySpinnerItemStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="mySpinnerItemStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.DropDownItem.Spinner">
        <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#00ff00</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to define custom background in style definition of your spinner. You can follow this [instructions](http://adanware.blogspot.sk/2012/03/android-custom-spinner-with-custom.html)

Comment: i am not asking for How to create spinner, why this view changing for api?